# loading local html5 in uiwebview with anchor

Tags: ios, html, uiwebview

I have the following code to load a local html file in an iOS app.

```
[WebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

The above works, however I need to load an anchor as this is a single page web app embedded in a UIWebview.

Basically how do I load index.html#settings for instance instead of just index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1777765) worked for me.

```
NSString *basePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"page.html" ofType:nil];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:basePath];
NSURL *fullURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"#anchor1" relativeToURL:baseURL];
// Now do whatever with this fullURL
```

The # is converted to %23 in `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:basePath]`, but `URLWithString:(NSString *)URLString relativeToURL:(NSURL *)baseURL;` not.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your question